# Do nylon and rubber bushes usually come in sizes between steel pipe sizes?

Tags: steel, pipelines, connections

I'm in Cambodia where I don't speak the lingo and I'm hoping to do a little DIY project.

If I were to buy two different off the shelf steel tubes am I right in thinking that the most common nylon and rubber bush sizes are always between these common tube sizes and I should have no problem finding say top hat bushes?

Also, is there more common lengths that these bushes come in, and if one can't find the right length is there generally long lengths of nylon bushing that they can cut down for you?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest including specifications of the off the shelf items. This will improve the chance of getting a good response.

Comment: You can always try to find or improvise a lathe, or use a cast-in-place material.

Answer (score 1):

The nylon bushings(below) that pull up first in google are 1/2 and 3/4 inch and seem the most common on other searches and are the cheapest of the bushings. They are used to make an air tight seal between metal pipes to transport fresh water. The 2 inch to 3/4th inch pipe bushing and pipes would be good for using for a bath tube and light irrigation, 1/4 to 1/2 would be good for a toilet and a 1/8th would be good for a refrigerator ice maker.  Depending on how much water flow you want will depend on what is the most common for that task.

[image: a]

Comment: These US customary inch pipe sizes are not necessarily going to be what is commonly found on the opposite side of the world from the US.